# count number of hierarchical childrens in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, join, common-table-expression, recursive-cte

I have a table that stores parent and left child and right child information. How do i count number of children belongs that parent?

for example my table structure is:

```
parent  left  right
--------------------
 1        2     3
 3        4     5
 4        8     9
 5        10    11
 2        6     7
 9        12    null
```

How do I count number of sub nodes for any parent. 
For example 4 contains following hierarchical child nodes - 8,9,12 so number of children are 3.
3 contains following sub nodes -> 4,5,10,11,8,9,12 so total number of children 7.

How do I achieve this using SQL query?

Comment: You can use a recursive cte to do this, just google it

Comment: possible duplicate of [Count all child nodes of hierarchical data in a table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6061025/count-all-child-nodes-of-hierarchical-data-in-a-table)

Comment: If this is a "nested set", it is anti-relational.  Please remove the relational-database tag.

Answer (score 0):

```
create table mytable
(   parent int not null,
    cleft int null,
    cright int null
)
insert into mytable (parent,cleft,cright) values (1,2,3);
insert into mytable (parent,cleft,cright) values (2,6,7);
insert into mytable (parent,cleft,cright) values (3,4,5);
insert into mytable (parent,cleft,cright) values (4,8,9);
insert into mytable (parent,cleft,cright) values (5,10,11);
insert into mytable (parent,cleft,cright) values (6,null,null);
insert into mytable (parent,cleft,cright) values (7,null,null);
insert into mytable (parent,cleft,cright) values (8,13,null);
insert into mytable (parent,cleft,cright) values (9,12,null);
insert into mytable (parent,cleft,cright) values (10,null,null);
insert into mytable (parent,cleft,cright) values (12,null,null);
insert into mytable (parent,cleft,cright) values (13,null,17);
insert into mytable (parent,cleft,cright) values (17,null,null);


DELIMITER $$
CREATE procedure GetChildCount (IN parentID INT)
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
    declare ch int;
    declare this_left int;
    declare this_right int;
    declare bContinue boolean;
    declare count_needs_scan int;

    create temporary table asdf999 (node_id int,processed int);
    -- insert into asdf999 (node_id,processed) values (1,0);
    -- update asdf999 set processed=1;

    SET ch = parentID;
    set bContinue=true;
    while bContinue DO
        -- at this point you are sitting at a ch (anywhere in hierarchy)
        -- as you are looping and getting/using children

        -- save non-null children references: -----------------------------
        select cleft into this_left from mytable where parent=ch;
        if !isnull(this_left) then
            insert asdf999 (node_id,processed) select this_left,0;
        end if;

        select cright into this_right from mytable where parent=ch;
        if !isnull(this_right) then
            insert asdf999 (node_id,processed) select this_right,0;
        end if;
        -- -----------------------------------------------------------------
        select count(*) into count_needs_scan from asdf999 where processed=0;
        if count_needs_scan=0 then
            set bContinue=false;
        else
            select node_id into ch from asdf999 where processed=0 limit 1;
            update asdf999 set processed=1 where node_id=ch;
            -- well, it is about to be processed
        end if;
    END WHILE;
    select count(*) as the_count from asdf999;
    drop table asdf999;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

---

```
call GetChildCount(2);  -- answer is 2
call GetChildCount(4);  -- answer is 5
```

I could supply a version that creates a dynamically named table (or temp table) and clobbers it at end if you want .  "dynamic sql / prepare statment" inside of a procedure. that way users **won't step on each other** with shared use of the work table asdf999. so this is not production ready. but the above gives you an idea of the concept