# Is 200 tables in a database too much?

Tags: php, mysql, database, database-design

Obviously this question is impossible to answer without more information, so let me expand.

Im building a stores database with about 1000 stores

They are divided into 13 major categories of products.

Those 13 major categories each have about 4 or 5 sub categories

Those 4 or 5 (about 65 total) each have about 4 or 5 of their own.

What ive done is make a table for every single parent and its direct children. And then tables for each of its children and their children.

In terms of logic, it will meet my programming needs, but i am wondering if this it completely unorthodox to have this many tables and if there is a better way to do it.

Also wondering if that many tables will overload/lag the system when querying.

I could have done the entire thing in like 2 tables, where i just assigned a parent_id to each category, but from a visual perspective that didnt look very organized or hierarchal, whereas this is like a perfect tree.

Comment: The superficial answer to your question is no, there's nothing wrong with having 200 tables in a database. However, as the answers below suggest, you usually shouldn't make multiple tables that all store the same kind of information. On the other hand, if each store type requires different information in the table, then having one table for each type might be the way to go.

Comment: 200 tables in the database is not bad provided the number of tables is  reasoned. The table that has 200 columns usually means poor DB design.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a relational database structure (with one-to-many or many-to-many relations) with proper indexing. Having a separate table for each category does not make any sense logically - this is why relational databases were invented.

Your solution should work, but in a datamatic sense, it's not very good practice.

**To get more specific**

A database structure like

```
TABLE categories:
id  title   parent_id(NULL)
```

Then sort the result you get from this using some recursion in PHP.

Answer (score 2):

If all of your tables have the same fields or mostly the same fields, and they represent the same thing (namely a product) then the solution that uses only two tables is the more standard way to design this database. One table lists all of the products and the category they fall into (the most specific category), and the other table lists the categories. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5995823/storing-hierarchical-data-mysql-for-referral-marketing/6011400#6011400) for a discussion of different ways to deal with the hierarchical information that appears in this table. The [nested set model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model) may also fit your needs here. (It's not discussed in that question, because it didn't meet the needs of the person who asked that question.) Depending on the model you choose, you may need to add a third table to implement the model.

Answer (score 2):

200 tables is overkill for the problem you describe.  You could store data about stores in one table, data about categories in another table, and data about subcategories in a third table, and finally a table about subsubcategories in a fourth table.  Then you could store data that pertains to a given store and a given subsubcategory in a fifth table.

You would tie rows in these tables to rows in other tables using the foreign key/primary key reference definition, and use join to combine data as needed.

It's much simpler, will perform better, and is more future proofed.  You can add new stores without altering the structure of the database.  Not only that, but you can do a variety of queries on the data once you've built the database.

Exploiting the same data in a variety of ways is really what databases are all about.  With your structure, you are going to have to write a new program every time you want to exploit the data in a new way.  With a classical design, you just have to write a query in SQL.

By the way, I have seen a database that has something like 400 tables in it.  But that database  managed all the administrative data for a mid sized university.  Everything from students, courses, enrollments, and grades to alumni donations,  high school transcripts, sporting events and parking spaces.  Your problem is not nearly this complex.

Answer (score 1):

This question is unanswerable, because you have not provided the most important information: load. How many users will be using this database? Equally importantly, which company are you using to host the infrastructure?

Also, poorly written code will result in a poorly-performing database.

All of that aside, make some small timing script for each of your pages. Determine how long each query takes, then multiply that by how many users you expect to have. If you expect to have 400 queries a second, then things like how you write your code and who you use to host the infrastructure will be pretty important pretty quickly.

Answer (score 1):

Some considerations:

In the multi-table scenario, you will need to keep adding more and more tables as the product/category etc grow, but it will keep lookups faster (full table scan of lesser records) and queries cleaner and relationships more sane.

In the two-table scenario where its usually a self join to get data, the lookups might become slower because all the data will reside in these few tables. Also from personal experience, they are a pain to maintain with so many codes and relations in the same table, especially when it becomes n-level parent-child relations. Oracle has relationship parsing SQL syntaxes for such situations which make the queries easier.But I think MySQL lacks them..

All things considered I would go with the first structure if I were you..Maybe flatten a few of the child-parent relationships, but mostly keep them atomic. (btw, I have worked with (legacy) MySQL databases with 400+ tables, so I think you should be fine with 200 odd tables)